# API loop, update GET request with next cursor

Tags: python, json, export-to-csv, nested-loops

I have a working loop that performs a GET request and then prints result data. What I need now is to make another loop that appends the cursor to the end of the 2nd and beyond request so each request can pull new data. So, the URL+cursor loop would contain my working data print loop.

I'm new to APIs but from what I gather request one produces a cursor and then you use that curse to find the next batch of data and then that batch has the cursor for the next batch over and over until there are no more batches and the cursor is blank.

I can get the first batch and the first cursor but I'm having issues using that cursor to find the next batch. Any advice?

PS - This example only loops 5 times but eventually I would make it loop until cursor is blank and print all the data to CSV.

```
import requests
import time
cursor=""

for i in range(5):
# api-endpoint
    URL = "https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?status=filled&sell_token_address=0xac98d8d1bb27a94e79fbf49198210240688bb1ed&cursor="

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
    r = requests.get(url = URL + cursor)

# extracting data in json format
    data = r.json()

    for index, items in enumerate(data["result"]):
        orderID = data["result"][index]['order_id']
        info = data["result"][index]["sell"]["data"]["properties"]["name"]
        price = data["result"][index]["buy"]["data"]["quantity"]
        decimals = data["result"][index]["buy"]["data"]["decimals"]
        print(index, orderID, info, price, decimals)


    cursor = data["cursor"]
    print("Cursor: ", cursor)
    time.sleep(1) 
    
print("END")
```

Comment: Are you sure that appending the cursor value to the URL is what's needed?

Comment: I forgot to add "&cursor=" to the end of the URL (fixed now) but ya I need to append each cursor to the end as the cursor value the next time through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rarely a good idea to append parameters to the URL. Much better is to use a dictionary and pass that to the requests function.

When you're making multiple calls to the same URL (albeit with different parameters) performance can be improved by using a session object.

This should give you an idea of how you could construct this code:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry


URL = "https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders"

params = {'status': 'filled',
          'sell_token_address': '0xac98d8d1bb27a94e79fbf49198210240688bb1ed'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    retry = Retry(
        total=5,
        status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],
        backoff_factor=0.1
    )
    session.mount(URL, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry))
    while True:
        (r := session.get(URL, params=params)).raise_for_status()
        data = r.json()
        for value in data['result']:
            orderID = value['order_id']
            info = value["sell"]["data"]["properties"]["name"]
            price = value["buy"]["data"]["quantity"]
            decimals = value["buy"]["data"]["decimals"]
            print(f'Order ID={orderID}, Info={info}, Price={price}, Decimals={decimals}')
        if (cursor := data.get('cursor')):
            params['cursor'] = cursor
        else:
            break

print("END")
```

**Note:**

Python 3.8+ required for this syntax

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Any way you can make it handle a Traceback error? I've seen Traceback handled with Try's but not seeing anything with what you provided.

Comment: This code will raise an Exception and the program will stop if the HTTP status code returned from GET is anything other than 200. Of course you can handle such exceptions with try/except but you first have to decide on your functional requirements - i.e., how you want to deal with specific status codes. For example, sometimes it might be helpful to retry

Comment: How would I have it retry the request with the previous cursor then break if that fails too?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how you could implement retries for a selection of HTTP status codes